# Make a request handle redirect by providing necessary parameters

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-4.0

I'm using jmeter to load test a Feature Page.

My jmeter requests (for that page) are being redirected to a login page.  How do I provide login info for that redirect?

I already tried:

Controller
 Login Page
 Feature Page
 Logout

But somehow a user even though already authenticated via Login Page is still being asked to login on the Feature Page.

Wondering if someone has a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you're **really** logged in as "green" result in JMeter doesn't necessarily indicates successful request. You can verify responses using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) 
   listener
2. Add [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan, if your application uses cookies for establishing/maintaining user session it should automatically resolve your problem
3. Inspect your test plan for any dynamic values (request parameters, headers, URL postfixes, etc.), if the are - they need to be [correlated](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Dmitri. I can confirm that the login is successful. I am using cookie manager as well. I have a controller with Login, Feature Page actions within it. The cookie manager is on the controller and not individually on Login and Feature Page. I will look into the correlation part you just mentioned.